# Не работает ТГ бот на Telebot

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

```py
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda c:True)
def tgchannelanswer(c):
    if c.data == 'sub':
        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        confirm_button = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text= "Я подписался(ась)✅", callback_data='confirm')
        markup.add(confirm_button)
        bot.send_message(c.message.chat.id,"&#128073; - https://t.me/+6mlwuanNntY1NWJi\n\n<b>После подписки нажмите на кнопку ниже</b>⤵", parse_mode='html', reply_markup=markup)
        bot.edit_message_reply_markup(chat_id= c.message.chat.id, message_id = c.message.id)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def data(call):
    if call.data == 'confirm':
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Всем привет", parse_mode='html')
```

Не могу понять, почему не работает, т.е не выводит сообщение "Всем привет"? Подскажите пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

В параметре `call` нет параметра `data`